# Definition of limit point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was giving the following definition:

> $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if there is an infinite sequence, which is contained in $A$ and each elements of the sequence is different from each other and from $x$, and the sequence convarges to $x$

So if we find just one sequence (That is contacied in $A$ and its elements are not all the same) that converges to $x$ it is a limit point?

I have tried to find the formal definition, this one was translated so it maybe a little inaccurate.

Comment: That definition is correct in a metric space; it is not correct for topological spaces in general. And yes, all it takes is one sequence, though if you find one, you automatically find infinitely many, since every subsequence of the one that you find will also work.